# Compute the power of $A$ for the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't see any examples in my book, nor have I read anything with regards to how I should solve this question.

The question is: Compute the power of $A$ for the matrix

$A=$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

$A^{19}$

Any help to get me started is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Diagonalization might ring the bell for you.

Comment: @NasuSama I guess I don't understand what is meant by "Compute the power" :(

Comment: Does it have something to do with an Identity Matrix?

Comment: It means "What happens when you multiply together $19$ copies of the matrix $A$?"

Comment: Otherwise, test this, using trials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplistic way to work out this problem without using diagonlization or any special method from linear algebra (except elementary multiplication of matrices) or anything from higher-level mathematics:

Suppose we are given the following matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

If we want to compute $A^2$, then we have

$$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

If we want to compute $A^3$, then we have

$$A^3 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

What about $A^4$?  Then, we have

$$A^4 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

It follows that if $A^n$ is a given matrix to the $n$th power, then we have the following relation (utilizing notations in an informal way. :D):

$$A_k = \left\{
\begin{array}{c c}
A & \text{if $k$ is odd}\\
I & \text{if $k$ is even}
\end{array}
\right.$$

where $A$ is the given matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix.  Thus, $A^{19} = A$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is diagonal, you have that the $k$-th power of $A$ is just the diagonal matrix where each diagonal entry of $A$ is raised to the $k$-th power (if you do not see why, proving it would be an easy and useful exercise).